Biopython Entrez module EFetch throws HTTP error 400 : Bad Request
Biopython Entrez module EFetch throws HTTP error 400 : Bad Request
I am trying to fetch the attributes of a PubMed article through PMID but when I use the EFetch method as below, I am getting an error - HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.
Esearch method works and didnt throw any error but when I use the EFetch method to extract the other attributes by iterating through PMID, I get the error. It is successful once in a while but fails mostly. I tried using the sleep method too and its still the same.
Entrez.email = "myemail@example.com"
Entrez.api_key = "api_key_generated_from_NCBI"

def fetch_pub_data(pmid):
    # Fetch PubMed record in XML format
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid, retmode="xml", api_key="api_key_generated_from_NCBI")
    record = Entrez.read(handle, validate=False)
    handle.close()
    try:
        # Extract publication date
        pub_date = record['PubmedArticle'][0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Journal']['JournalIssue']['PubDate']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        publication_date = "No Publication date available"
    try:
        abstract_text = record['PubmedArticle'][0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        abstract_text = "No abstract available"
    try:
        title = record['PubmedArticle'][0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        title = "No Title available"
    return publication_date, abstract_text, title

def search_pubmed(query, retmax=10):
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=query, sort='relevance', retmax=retmax, api_key="api_key_generated_from_NCBI")
    search_results = Entrez.read(handle)
    pubmed_ids = search_results["IdList"]

    # Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PubMed_ID', 'Publication_Date', 'Title', 'Abstract'])

    # Fetch and store information for the retrieved PubMed IDs in the DataFrame
    for pmid in pubmed_ids:
        pub_date, abstract, title = fetch_pub_data(pmid)
        new_row_data = {'PubMed_ID': pmid, 'Publication_Date': pub_date, 'Title': title, 'Abstract': abstract}
        num_rows = len(df)
        df.loc[num_rows] = new_row_data
        time.sleep(5)
    return df

# search query
search_term = ('((2024/1/1:2024/1/31[pdat]))')

# Search PubMed and fetch PubMed IDs with their respective publication dates and abstracts
results= search_pubmed(search_term, retmax=10) 
print(results)


This is the error that I get, when I execute this code
<ipython-input-1-f55c5b745c60> in fetch_pub_data(pmid)
---> 12     handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid, retmode="xml", api_key="#################")
     13     record = Entrez.read(handle, validate=False)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py in efetch(db, **keywords)
    194     variables.update(keywords)
    195     request = _build_request(cgi, variables)
--> 196     return _open(request)
    197 
    198 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py in _open(request)
    592     for i in range(max_tries):
    593         try:
--> 594             handle = urlopen(request)
    595         except HTTPError as exception:
    596             # Reraise if the final try fails

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

/mmm/jupyterhub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request```


